# How to use HttpWebRequest (.NET) asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, httprequest

How can I use HttpWebRequest (.NET, C#) asynchronously?

Comment: Check out this article on Developer Fusion: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4654/asynchronous-httpwebrequest/

Comment: You can also see the following, for a pretty complete example of doing what Jason is asking: http://stuff.seans.com/2009/01/05/using-httpwebrequest-for-asynchronous-downloads/ Sean

Comment: use async http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.endgetrequeststream.aspx

Comment: for a moment, I wondered if you were trying to comment on a recursive thread?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Use [`HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx)

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest;

void StartWebRequest()
{
    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), null);
}

void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    webRequest.EndGetResponse(result);
}
```

The callback function is called when the asynchronous operation is complete. You need to at least call [`EndGetResponse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.endgetresponse.aspx) from this function.

Comment: BeginGetResponse is not that useful for async usage.  It seems to block while trying to contact the resource.  Try unplugging your network cable or giving it a malformed uri, and then running this code.  Instead you probably need to run GetResponse on a second thread you provide.

Comment: @AshleyHenderson - Could you please provide me a sample?

Comment: @Tohid [here is a full class with sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224602/a-method-for-making-http-requests-on-unity-ios/12606963#12606963) I've used with Unity3D.

Comment: You should add `webRequest.Proxy = null` to speed up the request dramatically.

Comment: C# throws an error telling me that this is an obsolete class

Answer (score 73):

By far the easiest way is by using [TaskFactory.FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx) from the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). It's literally a couple of lines of code when used in conjunction with the new [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) keywords:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
var response = (HttpWebResponse) await Task.Factory
    .FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse,
                            request.EndGetResponse,
                            null);
Debug.Assert(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

If you can't use the C#5 compiler then the above can be accomplished using the [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx) method:

```
Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse,
                                    request.EndGetResponse,
                                    null)
    .ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        var response = (HttpWebResponse) task.Result;
        Debug.Assert(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
    });
```

Comment: Since .NET 4 this TAP approach is preferable. See a similar example from MS - "How to: Wrap EAP Patterns in a Task" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622454.aspx)

Comment: Way easier than the other ways

Answer (score 67):

Considering the answer:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest;

void StartWebRequest()
{
    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), null);
}

void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    webRequest.EndGetResponse(result);
}
```

You could send the request pointer or any other object like this:

```
void StartWebRequest()
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = ...;
    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), webRequest);
}

void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

Greetings

Comment: +1 for the option that doesn't over-scope the 'request' variable, 
but you could have made a cast instead of using "as" keyword. An InvalidCastException would be thrown instead of a confuse NullReferenceException

Answer (score 64):

Everyone so far has been wrong, because `BeginGetResponse()` does some work on the current thread. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx):

> The BeginGetResponse method requires some synchronous setup tasks to
>   complete (DNS resolution, proxy detection, and TCP socket connection,
>   for example) before this method becomes asynchronous. As a result,
>   this method should never be called on a user interface (UI) thread
>   because it might take considerable time (up to several minutes
>   depending on network settings) to complete the initial synchronous
>   setup tasks before an exception for an error is thrown or the method
>   succeeds.

So to do this right:

```
void DoWithResponse(HttpWebRequest request, Action<HttpWebResponse> responseAction)
{
    Action wrapperAction = () =>
    {
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback((iar) =>
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)((HttpWebRequest)iar.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(iar);
            responseAction(response);
        }), request);
    };
    wrapperAction.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback((iar) =>
    {
        var action = (Action)iar.AsyncState;
        action.EndInvoke(iar);
    }), wrapperAction);
}
```

You can then do what you need to with the response. For example:

```
HttpWebRequest request;
// init your request...then:
DoWithResponse(request, (response) => {
    var body = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    Console.Write(body);
});
```

Comment: Could you not just call the GetResponseAsync method of the HttpWebRequest using await (assuming you made your function async)?  I've very new to C# so this may be complete jibberish...

Comment: GetResponseAsync looks good, though you'll need .NET 4.5 (currently beta).

Comment: Jesus. That is some ugly code. Why can't async code be readable?

Comment: Why do you need request.BeginGetResponse()? Why wrapperAction.BeginInvoke() does not suffice?

Comment: @Gatis There are two levels of asynchronous calls - wrapperAction.BeginInvoke() is the first asynchronous call to the lambda expression which calls request.BeginGetResponse(), which is the second asynchronous call.  As Isak points out, BeginGetResponse() requires some synchronous setup, which is why he wraps it in an additional asynchronous call.

Answer (score 9):

```
public static async Task<byte[]> GetBytesAsync(string url) {
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
    using (var content = new MemoryStream())
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
        await responseStream.CopyToAsync(content);
        return content.ToArray();
    }
}

public static async Task<string> GetStringAsync(string url) {
    var bytes = await GetBytesAsync(url);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I ended up using BackgroundWorker, it is definitely asynchronous unlike some of the above solutions, it handles returning to the GUI thread for you, and it is very easy to understand.

It is also very easy to handle exceptions, as they end up in the RunWorkerCompleted method, but make sure you read this: [Unhandled exceptions in BackgroundWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044460/unhandled-exceptions-in-backgroundworker)

I used WebClient but obviously you could use HttpWebRequest.GetResponse if you wanted.

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

worker.DoWork += (sender, args) => {
    args.Result = new WebClient().DownloadString(settings.test_url);
};

worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) => {
    if (e.Error != null) {
        connectivityLabel.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
    } else {
        connectivityLabel.Text = "Connectivity OK";
        Log.d("result:" + e.Result);
    }
};

connectivityLabel.Text = "Testing Connectivity";
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 6):

.NET has changed since many of these answers were posted, and I'd like to provide a more up-to-date answer.  Use an async method to start a `Task` that will run on a background thread:

```
private async Task<String> MakeRequestAsync(String url)
{    
    String responseText = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();            
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            return new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
        return null;
    });

    return responseText;
}
```

To use the async method:

```
String response = await MakeRequestAsync("http://example.com/");
```

**Update:**

This solution does not work for UWP apps which use `WebRequest.GetResponseAsync()` instead of `WebRequest.GetResponse()`, and it does not call the `Dispose()` methods where appropriate.  @dragansr has a good alternative solution that addresses these issues.

Comment: Thank you ! Have been trying to find an async example, lots of examples using old approach which is over complex.

Comment: Will this not block a thread for each response? it seems quite a bit different to e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-wrap-eap-patterns-in-a-task

Comment: @PeteKirkham A background thread is doing the request, not the UI thread. The goal is to avoid blocking the UI thread. Any method you choose to make a request will block the thread making the request.  The Microsoft example you refer to is trying to make multiple requests, but they are still creating a Task (a background thread) for the requests.

Comment: That may be your goal, it's not mine and there's no way to say it was the OP's. For such a simple goal, it may suffice, but for say a web robot making many requests it will take on thread per request, which is very expensive.

Comment: @PeteKirkham I may be mistaken, but I believe the WebClient class from your link creates a thread for each request.

Comment: Maybe with six requests, but if you make it do more requests it can have e.g. 146 requests in progress on 68 threads (68 seems to be the limit for the number of threads it will spawn for more and more requests).

Comment: To be clear, this is 100% synchronous/blocking code. To use async, `WebRequest.GetResponseAsync()` and `StreamReader.ReadToEndAync()` need to be used and awaited.

Comment: @RichardSzalay, running the blocking code in a Task makes it async, but I did add an update indicating the limitations of the solution.

Comment: @tronman  Running blocking methods in a Task when async equivalents are available is a highly discouraged anti-pattern.  While it does unblock the calling thread, it does nothing for scale for web hosting scenarios since you're just moving the work to another thread rather than using IO completion ports to achieve the asynchrony.

Comment: @RichardSzalay Agreed. However, if the async methods like GetResponseAsync are not available, the above solution would be an acceptable alternative.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void GetResponseAsync (HttpWebRequest request, Action<HttpWebResponse> gotResponse)
    {
        if (request != null) { 
            request.BeginGetRequestStream ((r) => {
                try { // there's a try/catch here because execution path is different from invokation one, exception here may cause a crash
                    HttpWebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse (r);
                    if (gotResponse != null) 
                        gotResponse (response);
                } catch (Exception x) {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Unable to get response for '" + request.RequestUri + "' Err: " + x);
                }
            }, null);
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow up to the @Isak 's answer, which is very good. Nonetheless it's biggest flaw is that it will only call the responseAction if the response has status 200-299. The best way to fix this is:

```
private void DoWithResponseAsync(HttpWebRequest request, Action<HttpWebResponse> responseAction)
{
    Action wrapperAction = () =>
    {
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback((iar) =>
        {
            HttpWebResponse response;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)((HttpWebRequest)iar.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(iar);
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                // It needs to be done like this in order to read responses with error status:
                response = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            }
            responseAction(response);
        }), request);
    };
    wrapperAction.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback((iar) =>
    {
        var action = (Action)iar.AsyncState;
        action.EndInvoke(iar);
    }), wrapperAction);
}
```

And then as @Isak follows:

```
HttpWebRequest request;
// init your request...then:
DoWithResponse(request, (response) => {
    var body = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    Console.Write(body);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I've been using this for async UWR, hopefully it helps someone

```
    string uri = "http://some.place.online";

    using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {
        var asyncOp = uwr.SendWebRequest();
        while (asyncOp.isDone == false) await Task.Delay(1000 / 30); // 30 hertz

        if(uwr.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success) return uwr.downloadHandler.text;
        Debug.LogError(uwr.error);
    }
```