# How to handle exception raised in BackgroundWorker handler?

Tags: backgroundworker

I thought that the BackgroundWorker object will trap and pass exceptions raised in the DoWork handler to the RunWorkerCompleted hanlder but it is not happening to my program.

I created the following small program to illustrate the problem. Created wpf app.
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ExecBackgrpundWorker();
        }

```
    public void ExecBackgrpundWorker()
    {
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);


        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Do Work Exception");
    }
}
```

exceptions raised in  the bw_DoWork is never passed to the bw_RunWorkerCompleted.

How to properly handle this exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unhandled exceptions in BackgroundWorker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044460/unhandled-exceptions-in-backgroundworker)

Answer (score 1):

The exception is catched by the background thread and assigned to the "Error" property of the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs parameter of RunWorkerCompleted.

Comment: I read also that the backhround thread will catch the exception and pass it to the RunWorkerCompleted handler. However, I am getting Unhandled exception at this line. throw new NotImplementedException("Do Work Exception");

Answer (score 0):

It never makes it to "RunWorkerCompleted" handler.
it is failing silently.

My example is checking Active Directory for a list of security groups.
I've entered an invalid domain to test the error handling... silent.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
public void ExecBackgrpundWorker()
{
    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);


    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
    }
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException("Do Work Exception");
}
```

If you debugging and get Exception was unhanded by user code, click Continue then you will reach bw_RunWorkerCompleted. When you run your code as release it will always get to bw_RunWorkerCompleted.