# Multi threading in C# while downloading an image from the internet

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a function that loads an image from the internet. Yet, while it is loading, my application can't do anything else. Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
public static Bitmap BitmapFromWeb(string URL)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        myRequest.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myResponse.GetResponseStream());
        myResponse.Close();
        return bmp;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    load_avatrar();
}


private void load_avatrar()
{
    pictureBox_avatar.Image = BitmapFromWeb(avatral_url);
}
```

Comment: You can download the image on a different thread so application wont be stuck meanwhile.Please provide some code and more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming WinForms, you can simply point the picturebox to the source:

```
pictureBox_avatar.ImageLocation  = URL;
```

Nothing else needed.

Handle the LoadCompleted event to detect errors.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). It's meant to run exactly these kinds of operations in another thread to free up your application.

**UPDATE**

Based on your code, you could, with BackgroundWorker, have something like this:

```
private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    Bitmap b = BitmapFromWeb("some string");
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)SOME_METHOD_USING_BITMAP(b));
}
```

When the bitmap finishes downloading, `SOME_METHOD_USING_BITMAP` will be called with the result, and you can update your UI accordingly.

**UPDATE 2**

`SOME_METHOD_USING_BITMAP` will be your `load_avatar` method. Have it take a parameter of type `Bitmap`:

```
private void load_avatar(Bitmap avatar)
{
    pictureBox_avatar.Image = avatar;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Hmm... strangely it says "Error 2 Cannot convert type 'void' to 'System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker' C:\Users\Robert\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\XMPP\main\Form1.cs 74 26 main
" on this.Invoke( (MethodInvoker) load_avatrar(b) );

Comment: My fault. Using an anonymous method will make it easier: `this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { load_avatar(b); });`

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpWebRequest` class har support for this. You can use the `BeginGetRequest` method instead of `GetRequest` to make an asynchronous call instead.

```
public static void BitmapFromWeb(string URL, Action<Bitmap> useBitmap) {
  try {
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
    myRequest.Method = "GET";
    myRequest.BeginGetResponse(ar => {
      HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) myRequest.EndGetResponse(ar);
      Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(response.GetResponseStream());
      myResponse.Close();
      useBitmap(bmp);
    });
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    return;
  }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  load_avatrar();
}

private void load_avatrar() {
  BitmapFromWeb(avatral_url, b => pictureBox_avatar.Image = b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BackgroundWorker class to download the image asynchronously.
Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to the msdn page
Here is the good [tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker).

Answer (score 0):

Using Background worker is definitely a solution. However, the WebRequest class has a support for asynchronous calls. It will also provide better performance by using IO ports.

[How to use HttpWebRequest (.NET) asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202481/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-net-asynchronously)