# WebRequest.Create (MSDN example)

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm trying to create a simple webrequest for a json, i'm attempting to use the example on MSDN.

```
// Create a new 'Uri' object with the specified string.
        Uri myUri =new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");
        // Create a new request to the above mentioned URL. 
        WebRequest myWebRequest= WebRequest.Create(**myUri**);
        // Assign the response object of 'WebRequest' to a 'WebResponse' variable.
        WebResponse myWebResponse= **myWebRequest**.GetResponse();
```

I'm getting the following error;

A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

on the objects highlighted. (myUri and myWebRequest) Any idea's?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work because everything in Silverlight must be Async.  They force this because all execution on the main thread like a webrequest would lock the UI.  This approach provides a better user experience and is a trade-off to having developers master the use of threads for basic development activities.

See this:

[How to use HttpWebRequest (.NET) asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202481/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-net-asynchronously)