# HTTP over C# sockets

Tags: c#, http, sockets, web-crawler

I am trying to send HTTP request and recieve responce from the server over C# sockets, and i'm new with this language.

I've wrote following code (IP resolved correctly):

```
IPEndPoint RHost = new IPEndPoint(IP, Port);
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect(RHost);

String HTTPRequestHeaders_String = "GET ?q=fdgdfg HTTP/1.0
Host: google.com
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.205 Safari/534.16
Referer: http://google.com/";

MessageBox.Show(HTTPRequestHeaders_String, "Request");

byte[] HTTPRequestHeaders = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HTTPRequestHeaders_String);
socket.Send(HTTPRequestHeaders, SocketFlags.None);

String Response = "";
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) socket.ReceiveBufferSize];

int bytes;
do
{
    // On this lane program stops to react
    bytes = socket.Receive(buffer);
    // This line cannot be reached, tested with breakpoint
    Response += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
}
while (bytes >= 0);

MessageBox.Show(Response, "Response");
```

What am i doing wrong? I need just to load full HTML of page, or at least few characters from response (i cant do even this).

Comment: Use the `HttpWebRequest` class.

Comment: @SLaks I'd go one further - `WebClient`...

Comment: I need to create HTTP requst headers as a string, is it possible in these classes?

Comment: Why do you need to create the HTTP request headers manually?

Comment: you can add headers as a string, see my answer below

Comment: check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208015/using-httprequest-to-get-pictures-from-given-url 
and you can use httprequest async its more good.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Well, im trying to write simple server stress toold (like LOIC). This is my task for exam work in University. Socket's in this context is better and i need ability to write HTTP request to make better interface.

Comment: In your send "HTTPRequestHeaders_String" , missing 2 empty lines at the end : see https://gist.github.com/chouteau/c0a074f413d0800e818f7e357604d473

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest looking into the protocol itself if you want to do this raw, http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#Request

And try sending the CRLF to terminate the request ;)

Comment: Wow, i was like 5 hours on this problem and forgot to terminate request, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Now, your problem is solved, you have learned how create a Http header from scratch, It is time to switch to higher level of abstraction. As previously mentioned, use `HttpWebRequest` or  `WebClient`

Answer (score 1):

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
Stream responseStream = webClient.OpenRead("http://www.google.com");
if (responseStream != null)
{
   var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
   string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
   MessageBox.Show(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the Mentalis Proxy to be extremely helpful in understanding the Http Request/Response cycle at a socket level: http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/

Answer (score 0):

There is the `TcpClient` class which on one hand allows you to have a full control over the request (you create request body as string) and on the other hand is much simpler to use than a low-level socket.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx