# Call multiple HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I need to do several HttpWebRequest requests in a single moment, but when I make the request several times will cost a lot of time. I plan on doing each request in a separate thread and then get all the returns and put it all together when all calls are completed is it possible?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202481/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-net-asynchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.

Take a look at the msdn docs on [HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx)

I couldn't write a better example than in the docs.

Comment: In this case, for each request made, will be called in a different thread?

Comment: Right. You can kick off a bunch of threads, keep an array of ManualResetEvents, and then use WaitAll() to wait for all the web requests to finish.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Threading, but as they run asynchronously, getting a return value isn't an option. However, this thread : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/c43c0cce-491a-4ddb-9012-69929fab8e5e/ does point towards the ThreadPool class.