# blocking main thread until all async calls are done

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

This question had an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202481/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-net-asynchronously/202896#202896) on how to perform an asynchronous `HttpWebRequest`.

I have a list of 50k+ URLs that I want to asynchronously fetch with this method.  The issue I ran into is the main thread would complete and exit before all the async requests could finish.

I found `ManualResetEvent` could be used to `WaitOne()`, and to call `Set()` on the call back method.  This would work great if I was only doing one request.  Not sure how to handle this for many requests.

Comment: What's the point of doing async web requests if you are going to block the main thread during their execution? You're kinda killing the whole purpose of the exercise.

Comment: why don't use use Task-based Asynchronous Pattern and new `HttpClient` ?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov possibly a Console app and the OP needs to make sure the app doesn't exit before all the emails have been sent.

Comment: @James, yeah valid point. It's a pity that the OP hasn't provided this kind of information in his question.

Comment: Yea James is correct.  I'm doing a console app as a test, and I don't want it to end before all the requests are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use TPL:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var urls = new[] 
        { 
            "http://www.google.com", 
            "http://www.yahoo.com" 
        };

        var tasks = urls.Select(url =>
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            return Task
                .Factory
                .FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, url)
                .ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    if (t.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        using (var stream = t.Result.GetResponseStream())
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("-- Successfully downloaded {0} --", t.AsyncState);
                            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                        }
                    }
                    else if (t.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There was an error downloading {0} - {1}", t.AsyncState, t.Exception);
                    }
                });
        }).ToArray();

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good, I also found something like this `Parallel.For(0, 100, i => new WebClient().DownloadString(urls[i]));`  not sure if this really works the same or not, though.

Comment: @user17753 A `Parallel.For` will attempt to avoid creating a separate asynchronous operation for each iteration of the loop; it will try to chunk it up so that several iterations of the `For` loop will be done sequentially (because for CPU intensive operations this would be faster).  Given that each iteration of the loop is a long running IO task, that may not be as efficient.

Comment: @user17753, in this example you are not taking advantage of I/O completion ports. The `WebClient.DownloadString` method is a **blocking operation**. So you will be using way too much threads for this. In my example I am using a true asynchronous download without any blocking (except of course the one you've asked for at the end of the program).

Comment: As an aside, I found some kind of `AggregateException` is thrown at the `t.Result.GetResponseStream()` if the server gave a `4XX` or `5XX` response code.  E.g. 404

Comment: @user17753, that's why in my answer I test `if (t.IsCompleted)` before calling the `t.Result.GetResponseStream`, otherwise you could check for the exact exception.