# How to efficiently check an availability of a web service in c#?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a c# winform desktop app.  It is checking for messages on my Server by invoking my [web method].

As I am in development this [web method] is not always available for my test client to use.

Nevertheless the client is still invoking this [web method].

I have noticed in this scenario (on my PC build) that CPU usage goes to 25%.

At the moment my [web method] is invoked on my client in a `while(true)` loop. Subsequently, the [web method] is called recursively.

This while loop has been started by a new Thread.

I have a c# winform desktop app.  It is checking for messages on my Server by invoking my [web method].

As I am in development this [web method] is not always available for my test client to use.

Nevertheless the client is still invoking this [web method].

I have noticed in this scenario (on my PC build) that CPU usage goes to 25%.

At the moment my [web method] is invoked on my client in a While(true) loop. Subsequently, the [web method] is called recursively.

This while loop has been started by a new Thread.

```
Thread _th = new Thread(MyLoop);
_th.Start();


void MyLoop()
{
  while (true)
  {
    if (Disconnect)
    {
      return;
    }
    string[] _requests = Shared.WSconnector.GetRequests(Shared.ActiveMac);
    //do something with these server requests...
  }
}
```

Whilst the outage of my Web Services will hopefully be minimal it can obviously still happen.

How can i protect my client(s) from this CPU increase?

Thanks

Whilst the outage of my Web Services will hopefully be minimal it can obviously still happen.

How can i protect my client(s) from this CPU increase?

Comment: Could you show some code on how you invoke this [web method].

Comment: How often do you check? We have sth similiar where we test eriodically if other machines are reachable. You can also add a sleep in the while loop, so it does not bang against a not available system...

Comment: @Jite Hi, code added..

Comment: @Offler Hi, thanks for your feedback. I had considered putting a thread.sleep(1000) in but just wanted to check here first. The issue for me is that communications need to be real-time as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not call web client  in `while(...)` loop, but use a `System.Timers.Timer`.

The call itself make async: [How to use HttpWebRequest (.NET) asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202481/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-net-asynchronously), so no any CPU intense operation will be involved in all this.

This will lead, naturally, to slight re-architecturing of your code, but this is a way to go.

Comment: Hi, I had considered doing that as well. So do you think I should remove the Thread.  Put the 'web invoker' code in a timer and then use the async call within the Timer instead? Many Thanks

Comment: @AndrewSimpson: yes, I would schedule timer, *after* I get any type of responce from the service. So first get responce (success or failure), after start timer for next scheduler web service query. In this way I would  avoid that timer overlap response still in run, and start another response.

Comment: Cool, so In timer_tick event do: this.timer.enabled = false; 'invoke my [web method]'; this.timer.enabled = true;?  Thanks..

Comment: @AndrewSimpson: correct. run timer only on responce, that is.