# How can I prevent UI freezing while using HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#

I have a progressBar on my form and a button. 
When user clicks this button, the progressBar should be styled as "marquee" and the program begins to check is an URL is valid or not.. OK.

But when I click the button, the UI freezes until the HttpStatusCode returns true or false...

Here is the check code:

```
private bool RemoteFileExists(string url)
{
   try
   {
      HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
      request.Method = "HEAD";
      HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
      return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
   }
   catch
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

And here is the button click code:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.progressBar1.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
   var result = RemoteFileExists("http://www.google.com/");
   if (Completed)
   {
      //ok
   }
   else
   {
      //not ok
   }
}
```

Comment: You should use async methods:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202481/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-net-asynchronously

Comment: Use `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse()`. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202481/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-net-asynchronously

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `Exists()`-type methods are almost always bad design. It's usually better to just try and open/load a file, and handle the exception if (when!) it fails.

Answer (score 1):

The UI freezes because you are executing the `RemoteFileExists` method on the UI thread and receiving a response from a `HttpWebRequest` takes some time.
To solve this you have to execute `RemoteFileExists` in a different thread than the UI thread.
As your `button1_Click` method is already declared `async` the easiest way would be to declare `RemoteFileExists` as `async` too.
Then you can use the `HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync` method to asynchronously receive the response object.

```
private async Task<bool> RemoteFileExists(string url)
{
   try
   {
      HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
      request.Method = "HEAD";

      using(var response = (HttpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync())
      {
          return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
      }
   }
   catch
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Also when dealing with `IDisposable`s you should take care of releasing all used resources by using the `using` statement or calling `Dispose()`.
If you are using .NET Framework 4+ you can also use `WebRequest.CreateHttp(string)` to create your `HttpWebRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Putting it simple just use this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      this.progressBar1.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
      Thread thread = new Thread(() => RemoteFileExists("http://www.google.com/"));
      thread.IsBackground = true;
      thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
      thread.Start();


}
```

And do the check inside `RemoteFileExists .`