# C# need 2 threads for long execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a program that loads data from a SharePoint site.  It loads txt files, xml files, etc.  Any of these "load" actions can take a lot of time because of the user's connectivity to the SharePoint.  Therefore the whole windows form UI gets unresponsive until the data is loaded.

So I would like to know how can I easily create a thread for that "retrieval" of information while the whole windows forms UI still works and is operative.

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/202896/1218281

Comment: sorry did not understand that example. :(

Comment: [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: Don't create multiple threads, just perform the network query asynchronously.

Comment: @Servy isn't an asynchronous network call just a lightweight call to a separate thread?

Comment: @jdkorv11 No, it is not.  When done properly *there is no thread* doing any work while the network request is going on.

Comment: @Servy Is it just a callback then?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. I'm not going to provide exact code for any of them, but, I will provide you with research topics.

You can use a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx), [Task.Run()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) or manage your own threading by doing [Thread.Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc(v=vs.110).aspx). Do you need to fire off an event when the downloading is finished? If so, you can do something like this:

```
var task = new Task(() => DoSomething());
task.ContinueWith(() => SignalDone(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
task.Run();
```

The ContinueWith and TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext will ensure that the signaling will be done on the UI thread to minimize race conditions. You're on your own if you're doing databinding to anything being populated.