# How to do asyc and await on WebRequest?

Tags: c#, async-await, webrequest

So I have this code here. It gets images from **imgur** and sets a `Picturebox`.

**Code:**

```
private async void getImage(string imgUrl)
        {
            var  request = WebRequest.Create(imgUrl);
            using (var testing = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var str =  testing.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    addTablePic.Image = Image.FromStream(str);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Answer** (Edited)
 I have found one of the answer on this [How to use HttpWebRequest (.NET) asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202481/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-net-asynchronously).

```
private async void getImage(string imgUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                var request = WebRequest.Create(imgUrl);
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)await Task.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);

                using (var testing = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var str = testing.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        addTablePic.Image = Image.FromStream(str);
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

My question is how do I implement the `async` and `await` on `WebRequest`?

Comment: **Note:** regarding duplicate, the answer you seek on that page `isn't` the accepted answer (it was 2008 when it was written), rather the answers that make mention of `async/await`.

Comment: I am not really sure but I have look onto it. [How to use HttpWebRequest (.NET) asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202481/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-net-asynchronously) and one of the answers there worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The following sample code demonstrates how to use asynchronous calls with the WebRequest class. The sample is a console program that takes a URI from the command line, requests the resource at the URI, and then prints data to the console as it is received from the Internet.

The program defines two classes for its own use, the RequestState class, which passes data across asynchronous calls, and the ClientGetAsync class, which implements the asynchronous request to an Internet resource.

The RequestState class preserves the state of the request across calls to the asynchronous methods that service the request.

The ClientGetAsync class implements an asynchronous request to an Internet resource and writes the resulting response to the console.

```html
using System;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Threading;  
using System.Text;  
using System.IO;  

// The RequestState class passes data across async calls.  
public class RequestState  
{  
   const int BufferSize = 1024;  
   public StringBuilder RequestData;  
   public byte[] BufferRead;  
   public WebRequest Request;  
   public Stream ResponseStream;  
   // Create Decoder for appropriate enconding type.  
   public Decoder StreamDecode = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();  

   public RequestState()  
   {  
      BufferRead = new byte[BufferSize];  
      RequestData = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);  
      Request = null;  
      ResponseStream = null;  
   }       
}  

// ClientGetAsync issues the async request.  
class ClientGetAsync   
{  
   public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);  
   const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;  

   public static void Main(string[] args)   
   {  
      if (args.Length < 1)   
      {  
         showusage();  
         return;  
      }  

      // Get the URI from the command line.  
      Uri httpSite = new Uri(args[0]);  

      // Create the request object.  
      WebRequest wreq = WebRequest.Create(httpSite);  

      // Create the state object.  
      RequestState rs = new RequestState();  

      // Put the request into the state object so it can be passed around.  
      rs.Request = wreq;  

      // Issue the async request.  
      IAsyncResult r = (IAsyncResult) wreq.BeginGetResponse(  
         new AsyncCallback(RespCallback), rs);  

      // Wait until the ManualResetEvent is set so that the application   
      // does not exit until after the callback is called.  
      allDone.WaitOne();  

      Console.WriteLine(rs.RequestData.ToString());  
   }  

   public static void showusage() {  
      Console.WriteLine("Attempts to GET a URL");  
      Console.WriteLine("\r\nUsage:");  
      Console.WriteLine("   ClientGetAsync URL");  
      Console.WriteLine("   Example:");  
      Console.WriteLine("      ClientGetAsync someurl");  
   }  

   private static void RespCallback(IAsyncResult ar)  
   {  
      // Get the RequestState object from the async result.  
      RequestState rs = (RequestState) ar.AsyncState;  

      // Get the WebRequest from RequestState.  
      WebRequest req = rs.Request;  

      // Call EndGetResponse, which produces the WebResponse object  
      //  that came from the request issued above.  
      WebResponse resp = req.EndGetResponse(ar);           

      //  Start reading data from the response stream.  
      Stream ResponseStream = resp.GetResponseStream();  

      // Store the response stream in RequestState to read   
      // the stream asynchronously.  
      rs.ResponseStream = ResponseStream;  

      //  Pass rs.BufferRead to BeginRead. Read data into rs.BufferRead  
      IAsyncResult iarRead = ResponseStream.BeginRead(rs.BufferRead, 0,   
         BUFFER_SIZE, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), rs);   
   }  

   private static void ReadCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult)  
   {  
      // Get the RequestState object from AsyncResult.  
      RequestState rs = (RequestState)asyncResult.AsyncState;  

      // Retrieve the ResponseStream that was set in RespCallback.   
      Stream responseStream = rs.ResponseStream;  

      // Read rs.BufferRead to verify that it contains data.   
      int read = responseStream.EndRead( asyncResult );  
      if (read > 0)  
      {  
         // Prepare a Char array buffer for converting to Unicode.  
         Char[] charBuffer = new Char[BUFFER_SIZE];  

         // Convert byte stream to Char array and then to String.  
         // len contains the number of characters converted to Unicode.  
      int len =   
         rs.StreamDecode.GetChars(rs.BufferRead, 0, read, charBuffer, 0);  

         String str = new String(charBuffer, 0, len);  

         // Append the recently read data to the RequestData stringbuilder  
         // object contained in RequestState.  
         rs.RequestData.Append(  
            Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rs.BufferRead, 0, read));           

         // Continue reading data until   
         // responseStream.EndRead returns –1.  
         IAsyncResult ar = responseStream.BeginRead(   
            rs.BufferRead, 0, BUFFER_SIZE,   
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), rs);  
      }  
      else  
      {  
         if(rs.RequestData.Length>0)  
         {  
            //  Display data to the console.  
            string strContent;                    
            strContent = rs.RequestData.ToString();  
         }  
         // Close down the response stream.  
         responseStream.Close();           
         // Set the ManualResetEvent so the main thread can exit.  
         allDone.Set();                             
      }  
      return;  
   }      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    HttpWebRequest webRequest;
    void StartWebRequest(string imgUrl)
    {
        webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(imgUrl);
        webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), null);
    }

    void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var str = response)
            {
                addTablePic.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { addTablePic.Image = Image.FromStream(str); });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private async Task getImage(string imgUrl)
    {
        var  request = WebRequest.Create(imgUrl);
        using (var testing = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            using (var str =  testing.GetResponseStream())
            {
                addTablePic.Image = Image.FromStream(str);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `getImage` should be a `async Task` not a `async void` to be safe.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You are right. I forgot about it. Edited, thanks!